# hyperref: Height of page (\paperheight) is invalid (0.0pt)

Tags: hyperref, paper-size

I am getting the following annoying warning from `hyperref`:

```
hyperref.sty: [hyperref] Height of page (\paperheight) is invalid (0.0pt), usi
ng 11in. (page 1)
```

I am using a thesis class (`thesis.cls`) and some packages like `fancyhdr` etc. I compile using `pdflatex`.

I tried to fix the warning with this:

```
\special{papersize=11in,8.5in}
```

but it didn't help. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps post a small compilable code example (reduce a copy), see http://minimalbeispiel.de/mini-en.html it would make helping easier.

Comment: Where did you get `thesis.cls` from?

Comment: Since the OP hasn't returned since Aug '11 and the `thesis` class used doesn't seem to be the one on CTAN, I voted to close as _too localized_.

Comment: I had the same error from a custom beamer style I tried to make (not using `thesis.cls`). This question was the first thing that came up on google. It would be useful to have general tips on resolving this type of error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With this minimal example, containing all information of your post, the error cannot be produced:

```
\documentclass{thesis} 
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
text
\end{document}
```

So, there may be information missing. I also assume you mean the [`thesis` class](http://ctan.org/pkg/thesis) that we can find on CTAN.

Instead of manually adjusting lengths, I strongly recommand to use the [`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) package for that purpose:

```
\usepackage[papersize={8.5in,11in}]{geometry}
```

You may also specify margins and various other page dimensions using the `key=value` option interface. geometry calculates missing dimensions. Otherwise the user has to ensure that text width, left margin, right margin, binding offset and perhaps margin note width all sum up to the correct page width.

geometry autodetects the driver like pdftex or dvips.

Comment: For me, this changes the alignment of the text. It appears different before and after adding `\usepackage[papersize={8.5in,11in}]{geometry}`

Answer (score 21):

Okay, I found the solution. It it is broken in the `thesis.cls` that I'm using. But just setting it manually fixed it:

```
\setlength{\paperheight}{11in}
```

Comment: This one worked like a charm!

Comment: For me, this changes the alignment of the text. It appears different before and after adding `\setlength{\paperheight}{11in}`