# Using US Letter Paper with newlfm

Tags: paper-size

I am using the newlfm package, and want my output to use a US Letter 8.5x11 page size.  Unfortunately, I'm getting A4!

I have the following documentclass declaration.  The addition of "letterpaper" did not help.

```
\documentclass[stdletter, letterpaper]{newlfm}
```

I am new to LaTeX, so I'm still mostly lost.  I checked a couple other projects, where the simple `\documentclass{article}` results in the 8.5x11 size being used.

I am using MikTex 2.8 on WinXP.

Comment: Don't know if it matters, but have you tried removing the space in the option specification? I.e. `stdletter,letterpaper` instead of `stdletter, letterpaper`?

Comment: @Willie Wong: That should really not matter.

Comment: @TH.: my apologies. It was late at night and I was being facetious. There is hardly enough information in the question to say anything about the answer. It is not a system-wide setting issue as `\documentclass{article}` gives the correct size by default, and ostensibly (by the documentation) `newlfm` accepts the `letterpaper` option. Plus I couldn't replicate the issue. So I asked myself: given the limited information, what would *I* have typed differently? =)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After taking a break and then searching better, I came across [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2331/hyperref-height-of-page-paperheight-is-invalid-0-0pt/2343#2343) answer by @Stefan Kottwitz.  Adding the following line to my file successfully output the correct US Letter paper size!

```
\usepackage[papersize={8.5in,11in}]{geometry}
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the `newlfm` manual (Section 1.2), the `letterpaper` option to the document class should trigger the use of 8.5"x11" paper; however, it doesn't work either with my MiKTeX 2.9 -- you might want to contact the author and and let him know.

As you're resorting to `geometry` already, I recommend using

```
\usepackage[letterpaper]{geometry}
```

instead of manually declaring the dimensions. This is just a wee bit nicer and more "semantic". Even though I get an error message

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \geometry already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.
```

it does spit out letter sized paper, so it might just work out. For what it's worth, it's definitely not going to be worse than using `geometry` with the explicit declaration of the paper dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

Oops. I see that you're using MikTeX so my answer doesn't apply.

If you are using TeX Live, try running
`$ tlmgr paper`
and check that everything is configured to use letter. E.g., when I run that on my computer, I see

```
Current context paper size (from /usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-config/tex/context/user/cont-sys.tex): letter
Current dvipdfm paper size (from /usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-config/dvipdfm/config/config): letter
Current dvipdfmx paper size (from /usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-config/dvipdfmx/dvipdfmx.cfg): letter
Current dvips paper size (from /usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-config/dvips/config/config.ps): letter
Current pdftex paper size (from /usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-config/tex/generic/config/pdftexconfig.tex): letter
Current xdvi paper size (from /usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-config/xdvi/XDvi): letter
```

You can change all of them to letter by running
`$ tlmgr paper letter`
You may need to be root.

Comment: Good info, hopefully it will help someone else.  I gave it a shot, but I couldn't locate "tlmgr" on my system...

Comment: @mbmcavoy: Yeah. tlmgr is part of TeX Live. That's why my answer doesn't apply.